# Passive Peak Detection for microvolt input

Tags: signal-processing

Hello I am trying to find a peak detection circuit that is as passive as possible (ideally no battery needed) that takes an input signal of around 700 microvolts pk-pk.  All of the passive peak detector circuits that I have found use diodes making it impossible for me to use them with how small my input signals amplitude is.  Are there any other options that work for envelope detection of very small signals without having to use a diode or amplifier?  Any references on where I could start would be appreciated as I am having trouble with where I could begin.

Comment: what impedance and frequency?  what output?

Comment: The frequency of the carrier wave is 1-10Mhz and modulation wave is about 0.3 Hz.  I am not sure on the impedance.

Comment: Well Schottky diodes work to such levels but depends on current. But seems like a poor requirement to operate without voltage. Even a CMOS gate is only uA as a high gain linear detector.

Comment: What do you expect as an output? Maybe you could steal power from that?

Comment: "ideally no battery needed" - why?

Comment: You might want to google "RF detector. Just because a diode needs 700 mV to turn on doesn't mean it can't be used for this application.

Comment: @Samuel you can't use ampilifier for that signal?

Answer (score 1):

How about this? (from RF Design magazine of decades ago)

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fRwXGM.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: What is the point of the DC source branch?

Comment: By pre-biasing the diode to be "ON", microVolts PP at top node of diode will be rectified (or should we say ---- distorted) to cause a change in voltage across the Rout.